# Interpretation of Cohen's $f^2$ for effect size in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, effect-size

I am struggling with the interpretation of the effect size of a multiple regression model measured by Cohen's $f^2$. I know the guideline to determine if the effect is small, moderate or high, but what I am looking for is a simple explanation (may be in lay language) of the effect size for a multiple regression model. I looked into some resources but did not get any satisfactory answer. I have calculated the $f^2$=0.04 by the Gpower software for a given $\alpha$, power, and sample size. Can anybody explain what does this effect size mean, or how to interpret the $f^2$=0.04? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

From a simple Google search, I found this useful paper. I recommend reading it before continuing with your work, [A Practical Guide to Calculating Cohen’s f2, a Measure of Local Effect Size, from PROC MIXED](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3328081/). Albeit the authors use SAS, you should be fine interpreting your results in whatever software you choose to use.

From the paper, it reads

> According to Cohen’s (1988) guidelines, $f^2$≥ 0.02, $f^2$≥ 0.15, and  $f^2$ ≥ 0.35 represent small, medium, and large effect sizes, respectively.

To answer the question of what meaning $f^2$, the paper reads

> However, the variation of Cohen’s $f^2$ measuring local effect size is much more relevant to the research question:
>
> $f^2$ = $\frac{R^2_{AB} − R^2_{A}}{1−R^2_{AB}}$ 
>   (2) where B is the variable of interest (i.e.,
>   either smoking quantity or nicotine dependence score), A is the set of
>   all other variables (i.e., gender and depending on what B is at the
>   moment, nicotine dependence score or smoking quantity), $R^2_{AB}$ is the
>   proportion of variance accounted for by A and B together (relative to
>   a model with no regressors), and R2A is the proportion of variance
>   accounted for by A (relative to a model with no regressors). Thus, the
>   numerator of (2) reflects the proportion of variance uniquely accounted for by B, over and above that of all other variables (Cohen, 1988).

So in simple terms, the statistic shows the marginal effect size of including covariate B in the variable set, A, already in the model.

Comment: Thank you for referring me to this paper. I assume I was not clear enough to state my question. I know the guideline to determine whether the effect size is small, medium or large. What I don't understand how to interpret this effect size if I have to. Say, for example, I understand the interpretation of Cohen's $d$ when testing for mean difference. I was looking for some similar interpretation for cohen's $f^2$ as well. I will read the paper to see if it helps.

Comment: Please see the edits

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Now the meaning of the statistic is clearer to me.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please be sure to accept the answer to the question :)

Comment: Sure! Just wondering how could the interpretation you provided in simple terms apply in my case? I have 8 predictors and 3 of them are of my interest. So my $A$=5, and $B$=3 and I have an effect size of $f^2$=0.04. Can I express the marginal effect size in %? In general, how I can explain this numeric value to a general audiance?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but there are a lot of views and the question has not really been specifically answered so here goes:

You interpret Cohen's f^2 as quantifying the proportion of variance explained in a linear model relative to the amount of unexplained variance.  This generally works for different formulations of the linear model, like simple regression, ANOVA, multiple regression, etc.  The larger f^2 is, the greater the amount of variance your model explains relative to unexplained variance.

It is easy to calculate/estimate/guestimate too (given the usual caveats).  The paper cited previously by Jon is a good one.

[Selya, A.S., Rose, J.S., Dierker, L.C., Hedeker, D. and Mermelstein, R.J., 2012. A practical guide to calculating Cohen’sf 2, a measure of local effect size, from PROC MIXED. Frontiers in psychology, 3, p.111.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2012.00111/full)